# Equivalent of javadoc's tags in pydoc

Tags: python, pydoc

In javadoc, you can have tags like `@author`, `@return`, `@deprecated` which are handled specially when making java documentation. Is there an equivalent functionality in pydoc or am I limited to just a verbatim copy of the method's docstring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just switching to epydoc, which is much more featureful than pydoc. Sphinx is another alternative.

Answer (score 1):

for author:

```
 __author__ = "your name"
```

should work well.